# Can I use dependency injection in Corda oracle services?

Tags: corda

I want to swap currency in my CorDapp, but I want my currency swap service to be flexibility enough so that I can easily change the currency rate provider in the future.

Is there a way to inject a currency rate provider as Corda oracle services? Or is there any better way to solve my problem in Corda?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an oracle to provide the currency rate. To "inject" the currency provider to use, you could pass the name of the oracle as an argument to the flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class CurrencySwapFlow(val oracle: CordaX500Name) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val oracle = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(oracle)
                ?: throw FlowException("Unknown oracle service.")

        TODO("Use the oracle in your flow.")
    }
}
```